# Difference between to_server and from_client in snort

Tags: ids, snort

I am trying to wrap my head around the difference between the different flow options in `Snort`.

There are four directional flow options:

```
Option          Description
1) to_client    Trigger on server responses from A to B
2) to_server    Trigger on client requests from A to B
3) from_client  Trigger on client requests from A to B
4) from_server  Trigger on server responses from A to B
```

I cannot see the difference between rules 1 vs 4 and rules 2 vs 3.

`To_client` and `from_server` seem to have the same purpose.

And `to_server` and `from_client` seem to have the same purpose.

Is there a difference between these rules?:

```
alert tcp 192.168.0.0/24 any -> any 80 (msg:"Connection to HTTP port detected";flow:to_server,established;)

alert tcp 192.168.0.0/24 any -> any 80 (msg:"Connection to HTTP port detected";flow:from_client,established;)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically? No. The difference is in the logic. Do you want to focus on what's coming from clients or do you want to focus on what's going to the server? Where is your detection? When do you want to engage response actions?

Being able to split up the logic can be very helpful, especially if you want to chain rules and keep things straight.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me a practical illustration of how the difference in rule syntax might be helpful, maybe using the examples in my question? What different information would the second format give (from_client) compared to the first (to_server). As far as I can tell, they will trigger on exactly the same conditions, but I assume the alerts and logs will be worded differently, but how does that help?

Comment: There is no difference, as I said. It's only the logic that can be useful, and I have outlined different contexts where the different logic could apply.